# SQL How to create a table that continuously updates every time another table updates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-replication

I am trying to create a table of my customer orders. Unfortunately,  different parts of the order are found in different servers. Joining the first two server makes the query take 1-5 minutes, but joining the last server make it take multiple hours.

What I want to do is create a query takes a long time but runs once and combines all the data from the three servers onto one server and one table. Then every time a specific one of the table updates, my table gets updated as well (only on top).

Here is my query

```
 SELECT 
--*,
I.Date_Created
,I.Company_Code
,I.Division_Code
,I.Invoice_Number
,I.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number
,I.Total_Quantity
,Month( I.Date_Created) Month
,Year( I.Date_Created) Year

,CASE WHEN sh.packslip IS NULL THEN ph.SHIP_CITY ELSE sh.SHIP_CITY END City

,CASE WHEN sh.packslip is null 
THEN CASE WHEN ph.SHIP_CNTRY <> 'US' THEN 'INT' ELSE ph.SHIP_PROV END
ELSE CASE WHEN sh.SHIP_CNTRY <> 'US' THEN 'INT' ELSE sh.SHIP_PROV END
END State

,CASE WHEN sh.packslip is null THEN ph.SHIP_ZIP ELSE sh.SHIP_ZIP END Zip

,CASE WHEN sh.packslip is null THEN ph.SHIP_CNTRY ELSE sh.SHIP_CNTRY END CountryCode

,O.TotalPrice Total
,O.Email CustomerEmail

FROM [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Invoices I --Table one in server one

LEFT JOIN -- Table two and three in server two
    [JMDNJ-ACCELSQL].[A1WAREHOUSE].[dbo].pickhead ph (nolock) ON I.PickTicket_Number = ph.packslip

LEFT JOIN 
    [JMDNJ-ACCELSQL].[A1WAREHOUSE].[dbo].SHIPHIST sh (nolock) ON I.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number = sh.cust_po

LEFT JOIN -- Table four in server three, joining this one make the query go from one minute to an hour+
    [SHOPIFY].[shopify_moret].[dbo].orderwrappers O ON sh.cust_po = o.OrderName

Where I.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = 'ECOM2X' AND CONVERT(Date, I.Date_Created) >= Convert(datetime, '05/29/2019')
```

So I want this query to run once and build a table. Then every time the invoice table is updated, I want my built table to also get updated, and then check the orderwrappers table to add along the email and totalprice.

Then I can use my final continuously updated table for all future queries.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Sounds like you might want a [`TRIGGER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Doing this across servers is going to be painful no matter what. You may want to solve half of the problem by using transactional replication to make all the relevant data end up at one server. The remainder can then be solved by (indexed) views and/or plain triggers, but ideally you do want to get the remoting out of the way first. If you're strapped for resources you can do this with custom triggers and service broker queues, but otherwise just replicating the whole thing is easier.

Comment: As Tyler said, a [Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is the thing that you look for.
I would solve this by doing a trigger "on update" of the tables and I would insert the result of the select into your built table that you can check later.

Comment: Yes, the solution I am going to implement is going to be a transnational replication, I just don't know how to do that or where to start.

Comment: My suggestion of transactional replication is about using [SQL Server's own, built-in features](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication), and I suggest starting with the documentation.

Comment: Slight detour...the NOLOCK hint is not a good habit to get into or continue. It does lots of fun things like randomly return missing and/or duplicate rows. There are lots of other fun "features" of this often abused query hint too. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Is it just possible that your order either exists in ShipHist or in Shopify but not both? Seems to me that they have overlapping information and that you need outer joins to allow for that. And you really have 2 questions. First is how to get the initial set of rows and then how to keep those rows updated. Duplicating data is not without risk - think carefully about what happens when something goes wrong. Don't want to be in the news like Target, do you?